# How to align multiple floating elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'd like to align two elements (A & C) properly:

```
<div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
</div>
```

My stylesheet:

```
.a, .b {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 40%;
}
.c, .d {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 40%;
}
```

However, this results in:

[image: actual]

I'd like to align A & C like this:

[image: expected]

A JSFiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/foy79wz8/

Is there any way I can fix this?

**Note:** As the HTML code is produced by a third-party software I can not change the element order. I'm only able to specify a custom CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- Float `.a` and `.b` to the left
- Left-clear `.b`, in order to prevent it from being adjacent to `.a`
- Display `.c` and `.d` as inline-blocks
- Use `text-align: right` on the wrapper, in order to align `.c` and `.d` to the right
- Restore `text-align: left` on the elements.

```css
body {
  text-align: right;
}
div {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.a, .b {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.c, .d {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
<div class="d">D</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning your elements with absolute.

Here's my code:

```
body > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #faf;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
.a, .b, .c, .d{
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 20px;
}

.a{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.b{
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
}
.c{
    top: 0;
    right:0;
}
.d{
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see the below fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/foy79wz8/14/
```

code snippet is as follows,i have modified the layout slightly,

```css
body > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #faf;
}
.a, .b {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 40%;
}
.c, .d {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 40%;
}
.a {
    background: #faa;
}
.b {
    background: #ffa;
}
.c {
    background: #afa;
}
.d {
    background: #aaf;
}
.inlinee{display:inline-block;float:left;width:50%;}
```

```html
<div><div class="inlinee">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div></div>
    <div class="inlinee">
    <div class="c">C</div>
        <div class="d">D</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the question carefully before answering. The order of html elements cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... This works.. Just copy this code down. It works perfectly:

```
    body > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #faf;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
.a, .b, .c, .d{
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 20px;
}

.a{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
     background: #faa;
}
.b{
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
   background: #ffa;
}
.c{
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    background: #afa;
}
.d{
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background: #aaf;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kamal1990/pz39a39c/

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body > div {    
    background: #faf;   
}

div > div{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 15px;
}

.a, .b {width: 40%;}
.c, .d {width: 40%;}

.a {background: #faa;}
.b {background: #ffa;}
.c {background: #afa;}
.d {background: #aaf;}


div > div:nth-child(even){
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="a">A</div><!--
    --><div class="b">B</div><!--
    --><div class="c">C</div><!--
    --><div class="d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can flip the position of B and C with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or JQuery to do this changes without modifying html code

Comment: Unfortunately, no JavaScript is available.